# Apple Mail doesn't display the signature dropdown in new email from line to select manual Signature

Tags: mail.app, signature

I created multiple signatures for one Gmail account. Now depending on the context I would like to select a different email signature manually when composing an email. 
I created 3 different signatures for one mail account. In mail preferences, I set “choose signature” to "None”. for that mail account.

If I now compose a new mail, I don’t see the signature drop-down in the from line.

[image: New Mail to without signature drop down]

How could I fix that?

Comment: what happens if you select one of those signatures rather than "none." Does it give you the choice then?

Comment: @SteveChambers, then only the selected signature is added to the mail, but there is still no dropdown.

Comment: @Vadimo: Have you been through this for your resolution ? ->  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7793425

Comment: @Udhy, Thing is I don't see even the drop-down. But I tried the suggestions anyway. no luck so far.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the Library folder of your user folder. It is hidden, so press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to unhide all folders.
2. Go to

> **Mail/V7/MailData/Signatures.**

3. Move the two .plists to your desktop

Restart your computer, open the application, and test. If it works okay, delete the plists from the desktop.

Comment: doesn't work. Still no dropdown

Comment: @Vadimo: hope you have checked this alternative already https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7793425